# ERROR: run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++

I was trying to read a struct from a .text file and then save it in a new text file to see if it worked, but when it's getting saved the infamous error appears *"run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'pers' was corrupted"*.
I don't know which size I should give to the *struct persona pers* in order for it to work.
This is the .txt file:

> Mirio Togata
>
> 18937332
>
> 15/7/1951
>
> Shigaraki Tomura
>
> 17304739
>
> 24/11/1930

And this is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LNOM 32
#define TAM 2 /*The size I established for the struct persona is 2 because there are 2 people*/

struct fecha { int d, m, a; };
struct persona
{
  char nombre[LNOM];
  int dni;
  struct fecha nacim;
};

int readText(struct persona l[], int cant)
{
  printf("Leyendo...\n");
  char nom[LNOM];
  FILE *pf = fopen("persona.txt", "r");
  if (pf)
  {
    fgets(nom, LNOM, pf);
    while (!feof(pf))
    {
        strcpy(l[cant].nombre, nom);
        fscanf(pf, "%d", &l[cant].dni);
        fgetc(pf);
        fscanf(pf, "%d/%d/%d", &l[cant].nacim.d, &l[cant].nacim.m, &l[cant].nacim.a);
        fgetc(pf);
        cant++;
        fgets(nom, LNOM, pf);
    }
    fclose(pf);
  }
return cant;
}

void saveText(struct persona l[], int cant)
{
  printf("Grabando...\n");
  int i;
  FILE *pf = fopen("personados.txt", "w");
  if (pf)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        fprintf(pf, "%s\n", l[i].nombre);
        fprintf(pf, "%d\n", l[i].dni);
        fprintf(pf, "%d/%d/%d\n", l[i].nacim.d, l[i].nacim.m, l[i].nacim.a);
    }
    fclose(pf);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int cant = 0;
  struct persona pers[TAM];
  cant = readText(&pers[TAM],cant);
  saveText(&pers[TAM],cant);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use *actual* C++ idioms instead of C ones, that although work, are pretty error prone, as you just noticed.

Comment: What do you think this `leerTexto(&pers[TAM]` does?

Comment: `while (!feof(pf))` is a [not so good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a refresher of array indexing.

```
pers[0]
```

provides the first `persona` in `pers`.

```
pers[1]
```

would provide the second, and

```
pers[2]
```

would be the third. This sequence can go on for quite a while, but because

```
#define TAM 2
```

will substitute all `TAM`s for 2

```
struct persona pers[TAM];
```

becomes

```
struct persona pers[2];
```

so `pers` has only two valid entries. This also means

```
pers[TAM]
```

becomes

```
pers[2]
```

which we saw above gets the third element in `pers`, and we now know there is no third element in `pers`.

So

```
cant = readText(&pers[TAM],cant);
```

Gets the address of the non-existent third element of `pers` and passes it into into `readText` as `l`. Since `l` is pointing outside the valid range for `pers`, reading into the element pointed at by `l` will corrupt the stack and cause the error message.

The solution is to read into a valid element of `pers`, `&pers[0]` or `&pers[1]`. Since two entries will be read from the file by `readText`, starting with `&pers[1]` and reading into element 2 and the non existent element 3 is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wrote _**cant = readText(&pers[0],cant);**_ instead of _**cant = readText(&pers[TAM],cant);**_ and now it works perfectly

Comment: @Kuroki One minor improvement over that. [An array decays to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), so you can write `cant = readText(pers,cant);`